# Multithread call inside Twisted _delayedRender of request

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted, scikit-learn

I have simple Twisted webserver application serving my math requests. Everything working fine (I hide big code pieces which is not related to my question):

```
#import section ...

class PlsPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_POST(self, request):
        reactor.callLater(0, self._delayedRender, request)
        return NOT_DONE_YET

    def _delayedRender(self, request):

        #some actions before
        crossval_scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(pls1, X, y=numpy.asarray(Y), scoring=my_custom_scorer, cv=KFold(700, n_folds=700))
        #some actions after

        request.finish()

reactor.listenTCP(12000, server.Site(PlsPage()))
reactor.run()
```

When I try to speed up `cross_validation` calculation by setting `n_jobs` for example to 3.

```
crossval_scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(pls1, X, y=numpy.asarray(Y), scoring=my_custom_scorer, cv=KFold(700, n_folds=700), n_jobs=3)
```

and after that I got exactly 3 exceptions:

twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:12000: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

For some reasons I can't call cross_val_score with n_jobs > 1 inside _delayedRender.
Here is a traceback of exception, for some reasons reactor.listenTCP trying to start 3 times too.

[image: Exception traceback]

Any ideas how to get it work?

**UPD1. I create file PLS.py and moved all the code here, except last 2 lines:**

```
from twisted.web import server
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
import PLS

reactor.listenTCP(12000, server.Site(PLS.PlsPage()))
reactor.run()
```

But the problem still persists. I also found that this problem persists only on Windows. My Linux machine run this scripts well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scikit_learn apparently uses the `multiprocessing` module in order to achieve concurrency.  The `multiprocessing` transmits data between processes using `pickle`, which, among other... idiosyncratic problems that it causes, will cause some of the modules imported in your parent process to be imported in your worker processes.

Your `PLS_web.py` "module", however, is not actually a module, it's a script; since you have put `reactor.listenTCP` and `reactor.run` at the bottom of it, it actually *does stuff* when you import it rather than just loading its code.

This particular error is because since your web server is being run 4 times (once for the controller process, once for each of the three jobs), each of the 3 times beyond the first encounter an error because the first server is already listening on port 12000.

You should remove the `reactor.run`/`reactor.listenTCP` lines elsewhere, into a top level script.  A good rule of thumb is that these lines should never appear in the same file as a `class` or `def` statement; define your code in one place and start it up in another.  Once you've moved it to a file that doesn't get imported (and you might want to even put it in a file whose name isn't a legal module identifier, like `run-my-server.py`) then `multiprocessing` *might* be able to import all the code it needs and do its job.

Better yet, don't write those lines at all, write a [twisted application plugin](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tap.html) and run your program with `twistd`.  If you don't have to put the `reactor.run` statement in any place, you can't put it in the wrong place :).

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But the problem still persists, I updated the question. I also found that I got exceptions only in Windows. My linux server run this code well.

Comment: On Windows any "main" code should be guarded by `if __name__ == '__main__'` when doing multiprocessing. This is a very well-known problem; google for it.